# PHP Mcrypt extension fails all tests

Tags: php, mcrypt

I've been searching through Google and StackOverflow all morning for the answer to this, but nothing I've found yet has fixed this problem...

I'm running Mac OS X 10.9 with PHP 5.4.30 CLI.

I'm attempting to enable the mcrypt extension for PHP 5.6 in my MAMP environment. For some reason, 100% of the tests (`make test`) fail. This is what I do:

```
cd /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php-5.6/ext/mcrypt
phpize
./configure
make
make test
```

I see this error at the top of the results:

`PHP Warning:  Module 'mcrypt' already loaded in Unknown on line 0`

So I checked my copy of `php.ini`, but couldn't find `extension=mcrypt.so` so I don't know why it's failing.

```
=====================================================================
TEST RESULT SUMMARY
---------------------------------------------------------------------
Exts skipped    :    0
Exts tested     :   28
---------------------------------------------------------------------

Number of tests :   75                75
Tests skipped   :    0 (  0.0%) --------
Tests warned    :    0 (  0.0%) (  0.0%)
Tests failed    :   75 (100.0%) (100.0%)
Expected fail   :    0 (  0.0%) (  0.0%)
Tests passed    :    0 (  0.0%) (  0.0%)
---------------------------------------------------------------------
Time taken      :    7 seconds
=====================================================================

=====================================================================
FAILED TEST SUMMARY
---------------------------------------------------------------------
Test for blowfish compatibility [tests/blowfish.phpt]
Bug #35496 (Crash in mcrypt_generic()/mdecrypt_generic() without proper init). [tests/bug35496.phpt]
Bug #37595 (mcrypt_generic calculates data length in wrong way) [tests/bug37595.phpt]
Bug #41252 (Calling mcrypt_generic without first calling mcrypt_generic_init crashes) [tests/bug41252.phpt]
Bug #43143 (Warning about empty IV with MCRYPT_MODE_ECB) [tests/bug43143.phpt]
Bug #46010 (warnings incorrectly generated for iv in ecb mode) [tests/bug46010.phpt]
Bug #49738 (calling mcrypt after mcrypt_generic_deinit crashes) [tests/bug49738.phpt]
mcrypt_create_iv https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=55169 [tests/bug55169.phpt]
RFC 2144 test vectors for CAST-128 in ECB mode (bug #62102) [tests/bug62102_rfc2144.phpt]
Bug #8040 (MCRYPT_MODE_* do not seem to exist) [tests/bug8040.phpt]
mcrypt_cbc [tests/mcrypt_cbc.phpt]
Test mcrypt_cbc() function : basic functionality [tests/mcrypt_cbc_3des_decrypt.phpt]
Test mcrypt_cbc() function : basic functionality [tests/mcrypt_cbc_3des_encrypt.phpt]
Test mcrypt_cbc() function : error conditions [tests/mcrypt_cbc_error.phpt]
Test mcrypt_cbc() function : usage variation [tests/mcrypt_cbc_variation1.phpt]
Test mcrypt_cbc() function : usage variation [tests/mcrypt_cbc_variation2.phpt]
Test mcrypt_cbc() function : usage variation [tests/mcrypt_cbc_variation3.phpt]
Test mcrypt_cbc() function : usage variation [tests/mcrypt_cbc_variation4.phpt]
Test mcrypt_cbc() function : usage variation [tests/mcrypt_cbc_variation5.phpt]
mcrypt_cfb [tests/mcrypt_cfb.phpt]
mcrypt_create_iv [tests/mcrypt_create_iv.phpt]
mcrypt_decrypt [tests/mcrypt_decrypt.phpt]
Test mcrypt_decrypt() function : basic functionality [tests/mcrypt_decrypt_3des_cbc.phpt]
Test mcrypt_decrypt() function : basic functionality [tests/mcrypt_decrypt_3des_ecb.phpt]
Test mcrypt_decrypt() function : error conditions [tests/mcrypt_decrypt_error.phpt]
Test mcrypt_decrypt() function : usage variation [tests/mcrypt_decrypt_variation1.phpt]
Test mcrypt_decrypt() function : usage variation [tests/mcrypt_decrypt_variation2.phpt]
Test mcrypt_decrypt() function : usage variation [tests/mcrypt_decrypt_variation3.phpt]
Test mcrypt_decrypt() function : usage variation [tests/mcrypt_decrypt_variation4.phpt]
Test mcrypt_decrypt() function : usage variation [tests/mcrypt_decrypt_variation5.phpt]
mcrypt_ecb [tests/mcrypt_ecb.phpt]
Test mcrypt_cbc() function : basic functionality [tests/mcrypt_ecb_3des_decrypt.phpt]
Test mcrypt_ecb() function : basic functionality [tests/mcrypt_ecb_3des_encrypt.phpt]
Test mcrypt_ecb() function : error conditions [tests/mcrypt_ecb_error.phpt]
Test mcrypt_ecb() function : usage variation [tests/mcrypt_ecb_variation1.phpt]
Test mcrypt_ecb() function : usage variation [tests/mcrypt_ecb_variation2.phpt]
Test mcrypt_ecb() function : usage variation [tests/mcrypt_ecb_variation3.phpt]
Test mcrypt_ecb() function : usage variation [tests/mcrypt_ecb_variation4.phpt]
Test mcrypt_ecb() function : usage variation [tests/mcrypt_ecb_variation5.phpt]
mcrypt_enc_get_algorithms_name [tests/mcrypt_enc_get_algorithms_name.phpt]
mcrypt_enc_get_block_size [tests/mcrypt_enc_get_block_size.phpt]
mcrypt_enc_get_iv_size [tests/mcrypt_enc_get_iv_size.phpt]
mcrypt_enc_get_key_size [tests/mcrypt_enc_get_key_size.phpt]
mcrypt_enc_get_modes_name [tests/mcrypt_enc_get_mode_name.phpt]
mcrypt_enc_get_supported_key_sizes [tests/mcrypt_enc_get_supported_key_sizes.phpt]
mcrypt_enc_is_block_algorithm [tests/mcrypt_enc_is_block_algorithm.phpt]
mcrypt_enc_is_block_algorithm_mode [tests/mcrypt_enc_is_block_algorithm_mode.phpt]
mcrypt_enc_is_block_mode [tests/mcrypt_enc_is_block_mode.phpt]
mcrypt_enc_self_test [tests/mcrypt_enc_self_test.phpt]
Test mcrypt_encrypt() function : TripleDES functionality [tests/mcrypt_encrypt_3des_cbc.phpt]
Test mcrypt_encrypt() function : TripleDES functionality [tests/mcrypt_encrypt_3des_ecb.phpt]
Test mcrypt_encrypt() function : error conditions [tests/mcrypt_encrypt_error.phpt]
Test mcrypt_encrypt() function : usage variation - different types for cipher [tests/mcrypt_encrypt_variation1.phpt]
Test mcrypt_encrypt() function : usage variation [tests/mcrypt_encrypt_variation2.phpt]
Test mcrypt_encrypt() function : usage variation [tests/mcrypt_encrypt_variation3.phpt]
Test mcrypt_encrypt() function : usage variation [tests/mcrypt_encrypt_variation4.phpt]
Test mcrypt_encrypt() function : usage variation [tests/mcrypt_encrypt_variation5.phpt]
mcrypt filters [tests/mcrypt_filters.phpt]
mcrypt_get_block_size [tests/mcrypt_get_block_size.phpt]
mcrypt_get_cipher_name [tests/mcrypt_get_cipher_name.phpt]
mcrypt_enc_get_iv_size [tests/mcrypt_get_iv_size.phpt]
mcrypt_get_key_size [tests/mcrypt_get_key_size.phpt]
mcrypt_list_algorithms [tests/mcrypt_list_algorithms.phpt]
mcrypt_list_modes [tests/mcrypt_list_modes.phpt]
mcrypt_module_get_algo_block_size [tests/mcrypt_module_get_algo_block_size.phpt]
mcrypt_module_get_algo_key_size [tests/mcrypt_module_get_algo_key_size.phpt]
mcrypt_module_get_supported_key_sizes [tests/mcrypt_module_get_supported_key_sizes.phpt]
mcrypt_module_is_block_algorithm [tests/mcrypt_module_is_block_algorithm.phpt]
mcrypt_module_is_block_algorithm_mode [tests/mcrypt_module_is_block_algorithm_mode.phpt]
mcrypt_module_is_block_mode [tests/mcrypt_module_is_block_mode.phpt]
mcrypt_module_open [tests/mcrypt_module_open.phpt]
mcrypt_module_self_test [tests/mcrypt_module_self_test.phpt]
mcrypt_ofb [tests/mcrypt_ofb.phpt]
Test mcrypt_encrypt() function : AES functionality [tests/mcrypt_rijndael128_128BitKey.phpt]
Test mcrypt_encrypt() function : AES functionality [tests/mcrypt_rijndael128_256BitKey.phpt]
=====================================================================
```

Comment: "already loaded in unknown" usually means the module was compiled into php.

Comment: @MarcB ah, ok. I checked and you're right, I compiled with `--with-mcrypt`, so should I recompile without that flag?

Comment: probably, but then there's no guarantee that the version you've compiled will pass the tests anyways.